# Unable to use registerlistener to use the Step_counter - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sensors

I want to use the STEP_COUNTER using the sensor from the phone.
There is my code:

```
public class ContarPassos extends Fragment {

private SensorManager sensorManager;
private TextView count;
boolean running;

Toolbar toolbar;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contar_passos,null);

    toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_passos);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.passos);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    running = true;
    Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    if(countSensor != null) {
        sensorManager.registerListener(getActivity(), countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Count sensor not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    running = false;
}


public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(running) {
        count.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
    }
}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

My Problem is in this line:

```
sensorManager.registerListener(getActivity(), countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
```

I'm using fragments and I think when we use fragments we use getActivity instead "this"
I already try to cast the "getActivity" but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to implement the SensorEventListener in the class declaration

```
public class ContarPassos extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {
...
}
```

then when registering the callback have the first argument as "this" instead of getActivity()

```
(sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
```

give that a shot, this is my first post on StackOverflow and I am a rookie programmer but hopefully I could help!